# Use django with firestore, Non-relational database

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

Can I use Firestore with django python being firestore a non-relational database? if it is not the case, Django-non-rel is the option?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and found a library called [django-firebase-orm](https://pypi.org/project/django-firebase-orm/). I assume it'll map Django's relational model onto firestore.